# iOS didSelectRowAt row on UITableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to follow-up with this tutorial on CodePath: Visit https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Search-Bar-Guide#cancelling-out-of-search-and-hiding-keyboard

I created a SearchViewController to search but then **didSelectRowAt** doesn't work

This is my code below:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
                "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
                "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
                "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
                "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]

    var filteredData: [String]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.allowsSelection = true
        searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = data
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }


    // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAt(\(indexPath)")
    }

    // This method updates filteredData based on the text in the Search Box
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        // When there is no text, filteredData is the same as the original data
        // When user has entered text into the search box
        // Use the filter method to iterate over all items in the data array
        // For each item, return true if the item should be included and false if the
        // item should NOT be included
        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data!.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Is there something else I need to do? The tutorial doesn't show any other code I was missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should the `UITableViewDelegate` delegate to your class and `tableView.delegate  = self` in your `viewDidLoad` function. This will help to trigger the delegates functions of the `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

In Your viewDidLoad() method

```
 tableView.delegate = self
 tableView.dataSource = self
```